# Using jQuery to group varying number of divs wtih same class until "last" class

Tags: jquery, grouping

I've seen other related questions but not quite like mine.

I have blocks of code with varying number of rows and want to group those rows, including the "last" div:

```
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="last"></div>
<br>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="last"></div>
<br>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="last"></div>
```

I want:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="last"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="last"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="last"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried various find, addBefore, wrapAll variations but just can't get it.

I've tried variations of:

```
$(this).find(".row, .last").wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can acheive this by combining prevAll and wrapAll. Below is the ocde

```
$("div.last").each(function() {
  $(this).prevAll(".row").addBack().wrapAll("<div class='wrapper' />"); 
});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/wx8074qn/3/

Comment: This works too.  And, less code.  'prevAll' is what I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:-

```js
//find all the 'first' .row by checking the previous is not a .row
$('.row').prev(':not(.row)').next().each(function() {
  //wrap all next elements until you find something not a div
  $(this).nextUntil(':not(div)').addBack().wrapAll($("<div></div>", {
    class: 'wrapper'
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="last"></div>
<br>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="last"></div>
<br>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="last"></div>
```